# GCC doesn't like to make friends with anonymous namespace forward declarations, but MSVC does. What?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

This code compiles on MSVC but not on GCC, when testing on [GodBolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/f5YqY7)

The Baz class is declared in the anonymous namespace, which makes GCC think it's a different class than what I then define below, but MSVC seems to connect them.

```
namespace { class Baz; }

class Foo { protected: int x; };
class Bar : public Foo { friend class Baz; };

namespace {
  class Baz { void f() { Bar b; b.x = 42; } };
}
```

What is correct according to the standard?

Comment: @user7860670 Updated with typo, sorry.

Comment: @Bathsheba we're not seeing/finding the combination that makes it compile on MSVC, as you state. Can you show us the link to a godbolt page that compiles it on MSVC?

Comment: @Jeffrey I made the godbolt link in the Q contain the code now. Should've done that from start.

Comment: You can get rid of the inheritance and just have `class Bar { friend class Baz; protected: int x; };`. I can still reproduce it with that - compiles with msvc and clang but not gcc.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19872920/is-it-possible-to-friend-a-class-in-an-anonymous-namespace-in-c) may be relevant.

Comment: Well, clang compiles it just fine so i'd assume that it is an issue with gcc. Looks like [Bug 71882](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71882)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a discrepancy in the language wording, with different compilers taking different sides on the issue. MSVC and clang will accept the code as-is, but compilers like GCC and Edge reject it.

The conflicting wording comes from:

**10.3.1.2 [namespace.memdef]**

> ... the lookup to determine whether the entity has been previously declared **shall not consider any scopes outside the innermost enclosing namespace.**

The struct `Baz` is not declared in the innermost enclosing namespace, but it is visible there, so normal name lookup would find it. But since this isn't normal name lookup, Compilers like gcc and Edge don't look into the enclosing namespaces, only the innermost.

This information is from this filed [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71882) which discusses the topic.

It appears that MSVC and Edge choose to interpret using anonymous namespaces differently, which would transform OP's code to the following:

```cpp
namespace unnamed { }
using namespace unnamed;
namespace unnamed { struct Baz; }

class Foo { protected: int x; };
class Bar : public Foo { friend class Baz; };

namespace unnamed { class Baz { void f() { Bar b; b.x = 42; } }; }
```

This equivalent code is also rejected by compilers like gcc and Edge, but accepted by MSVC and clang due to a different interpretation of whether types that are brought in via `using` declarations or directives are considered for `friend` name lookup. More can be seen on this issue at [cwg-138](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#138)

Comment: _Compilers like gcc and Edge choose not to continue looking into enclosing namespaces where MSVC and Edge will_ Ehm? Nobody looks into **enclosing** namespaces, the question is: should the lookup see through using-directives. Anonymous NS doesn't enclose the global NS.

Comment: I'm not commenting on the correctness of either interpretation, I am simply indicating where the discrepancy comes from as was mentioned in the linked gcc bug report. I also edited my answer 15 seconds before your comment which includes the fact that GCC does not find `friend` name lookup through `using`-directives due to a discrepancy relating to using directives, as you mentioned

Comment: _I also edited my answer 15 seconds before your comment_ I still see the sentense about enclosing namespaces...

Comment: That's because my remark is almost verbatim what Jonathon Wakely said in the bug report for an almost identical example.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are using an elaborated type specifier for the friendship declaration and GCC use it to declares a class `Baz` in the global namespace. [An elaborated type specifier is a declaration](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab) [unless a previous declaration is found in the inner most enclosing namespace](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.elab#2.sentence-3). Apparently it is not clear if the declaration of `Baz` should be considered to be in global namespace.

To fix this, just use the name of the class in the friend declaration:

```
namespace { class Baz; }

class Foo { protected: int x; };
class Bar : public Foo { friend Baz; };

namespace {
  class Baz { void f() { Bar b; b.x = 42; } };
}
```

*The use of elaborated type specifier in a friend declaration is an idiomatic pathological habit. There is no reason to use elaborated type specifier unless the name of the type is also the name of a variable.*

Comment: TIL that I've been using elaborated type specifiers for friendship my entire life. I did not know this. I imagine you would still need elaborated specifiers for the likes of friendship across class templates though?

Comment: _your code declare a class Baz in the global namespace_ If the lookup doesn't find a preceding declaration. And the question is should lookup look up through using-directives.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Fixed.

Comment: _An elaborated type specifier is a declaration unless a previous declaration is found_ [**in the innermost enclosing namespace**](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#namespace.memdef-3.sentence-5). _So GCC is wrong_ It is not 100% clear.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer OK, is there no open issue for this ambiguity?

Comment: Awesomesauce! Thanks for teaching us about elaborated type specifiers!

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous namespaces act as if they have a unique name and are only available to the current translation unit.

It seems plausible that some compilers would give all anonymous namespaces within a translation unit the same name, and others might not (just a guess at a possible implementation), but seems not like something you can rely on.

More details about anonymous namespaces can be found here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces

Comment: I don't know if that's relevant here, though. If you change the initial declaration to `namespace { class Baz { }; }` (defining `Baz`), gcc will give a "redefinition of 'class {anonymous}::Baz'" error, so the two anonymous namespaces are being considered as the same space.

Comment: Indeed it seems like unspecified according to your link. Also, according to the bug link above, EDG and GCC went one way, Clang and MSVC the other. Of course. :)

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm OTOH, since it's an implied "using <anon1>" after the first, it makes sense that it clashes since the current lookup already has Baz from the first anon namespace, even inside the second anon namespace.